# Restructure a json object array to show data in tabular format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I want to restructure a json object array to show data in tabular format. I have managed to create an object with name as key and values as an array of each type using below lodash command

`const grouped = _.groupBy(dayTargetDetails, trgt => trgt.NAME);`

And I want the data in below format

| Fruit | 10/01 | 10/02 | 10/03 | 10/04 | 10/05 | ... | till month end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 45 | 75 | 15 | 64 | 19 | .. |  |
| Orange | 18 | 26 |  |  |  | .. |  |

## Sample JSON Data:

```
const dayTargetDetails = [
    {
        "NAME": "APPLE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-01",
        "ORDERS": 45
    },
    {
        "NAME": "APPLE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-02",
        "ORDERS": 75
    },
    {
        "NAME": "APPLE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-03",
        "ORDERS": 15
    },
    {
        "NAME": "APPLE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-04",
        "ORDERS": 64
    },
    {
        "NAME": "APPLE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-05",
        "ORDERS": 19
    },
    {
        "NAME": "ORANGE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-01",
        "ORDERS": 18
    },
    {
        "NAME": "ORANGE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-02",
        "ORDERS": 26
    }
]
```

Comment: can you show that table as an object? or show the tabular format you want.

Comment: @j.ian.le Im looking for a method which returns the data in linear format (as shown in tabular format) in json so that I can loop through and show it in angular html table.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to compile the JSON records into corresponding `NAME` categories:

```js
function compileDayTD(dayTargetDetails) {
    return dayTargetDetails.reduce(function (prev, itm) {

        // check for existing NAME key, instantiate with array if none
        (undefined !== prev[itm.NAME] || (prev[itm.NAME] = [])) 
    
        // append item to NAME array
        && prev[itm.NAME].push(itm);

        return prev;
    }, {});
}

const dayTargetDetails = [
    {
        "NAME": "APPLE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-01",
        "ORDERS": 45
    },
    {
        "NAME": "APPLE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-02",
        "ORDERS": 75
    },
    {
        "NAME": "APPLE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-03",
        "ORDERS": 15
    },
    {
        "NAME": "APPLE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-04",
        "ORDERS": 64
    },
    {
        "NAME": "APPLE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-05",
        "ORDERS": 19
    },
    {
        "NAME": "ORANGE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-01",
        "ORDERS": 18
    },
    {
        "NAME": "ORANGE",
        "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-02",
        "ORDERS": 26
    }
]

console.log(compileDayTD(dayTargetDetails));
```

Produces the JSON object:

```
{
  "APPLE": [
    {
      "NAME": "APPLE",
      "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-01",
      "ORDERS": 45
    },
    {
      "NAME": "APPLE",
      "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-02",
      "ORDERS": 75
    },
    {
      "NAME": "APPLE",
      "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-03",
      "ORDERS": 15
    },
    {
      "NAME": "APPLE",
      "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-04",
      "ORDERS": 64
    },
    {
      "NAME": "APPLE",
      "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-05",
      "ORDERS": 19
    }
  ],
  "ORANGE": [
    {
      "NAME": "ORANGE",
      "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-01",
      "ORDERS": 18
    },
    {
      "NAME": "ORANGE",
      "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-02",
      "ORDERS": 26
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code defines two functions `tabulate` and `tabulatedToString`.

Function `tabulate` takes the input data, the names of the horizontal and vertical fields to be used in the tabulation, and the name of the field to be used for the table cell value.

The input data is enumerated; the horizontal and vertical headings are populated; and row objects are created and populated, keyed on the vertical field (here, the date). `cellZero` is the value to be used in the top left corner of the table.

Function `tabulatedToString` provides an example transformation of the tabulated data to a formatted string; this would need tweaking to output an HTML table.

```js
const data = [
  { "NAME": "APPLE", "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-01", "ORDERS": 45 }, 
  { "NAME": "APPLE", "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-02", "ORDERS": 75 }, 
  { "NAME": "APPLE", "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-03", "ORDERS": 15 }, 
  { "NAME": "APPLE", "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-04", "ORDERS": 64 }, 
  { "NAME": "APPLE", "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-05", "ORDERS": 19 }, 
  { "NAME": "ORANGE", "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-01", "ORDERS": 18 }, 
  { "NAME": "ORANGE", "ORDER_DT": "2022-10-02", "ORDERS": 26 }]

const tabulate = (data, { x, y, cellZero = y, v }) => {
    const xHeadings = new Set
    const yHeadings = new Set
    const rows = new Map
    
    for(let d of data) {
        rows.get(d[y]) || rows.set(d[y], {})        
        xHeadings.add(d[x])
        yHeadings.add(d[y])
        rows.get(d[y])[d[x]] = d[v]
    }
    
    return { cellZero, xHeadings, yHeadings, rows }
}

const tablulatedToString = ({ cellZero, xHeadings, yHeadings, rows }) => {
    const acc = [`${cellZero} | ${[...xHeadings].join(' |')}`]
    
    for(let yh of yHeadings) {
       const row = [`${yh}`]
       
       for(let xh of xHeadings) {
          row.push(rows.get(yh)[xh])
       }
       
       acc.push(row.join(' | '))
    }
    
    return acc.join('\n')
}

const options = { x: 'ORDER_DT', y: 'NAME', cellZero: 'Fruit', v: 'ORDERS' }
const tabulated = tabulate(data, options)
console.log(tablulatedToString(tabulated))
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this scenario in one of my project using Angular.

For folks who would look for an answer in future below is how I achieved the end result.

```
const grouped = _.groupBy(this.dayTargetDetails, trgt => trgt.NAME);

Object.keys(grouped).forEach((key) => {
    let data = grouped[key];
    var result = new DayTargetsTable();
    result.NAME = key;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result["DAY_"+this.datePipe.transform(new Date(data[i].ORDER_DT), 'd')] = data[i].ORDERS;
    }
    this.dayTargetTableDataList.push(result);
    });
    console.log(this.dayTargetTableDataList);
```

DayTargetsTable is the typescript model file

```
export class DayTargetsTable {
    NAME: string;
    DAY_1?: number;
    DAY_2?: number;
    DAY_3?: number;
    DAY_4?: number;
    DAY_5?: number;
    DAY_6?: number;
    DAY_7?: number;
    DAY_8?: number;
    DAY_9?: number;
    DAY_10?: number;
    DAY_11?: number;
    DAY_12?: number;
    DAY_13?: number;
    DAY_14?: number;
    DAY_15?: number;
    DAY_16?: number;
    DAY_17?: number;
    DAY_18?: number;
    DAY_19?: number;
    DAY_20?: number;
    DAY_21?: number;
    DAY_22?: number;
    DAY_23?: number;
    DAY_24?: number;
    DAY_25?: number;
    DAY_26?: number;
    DAY_27?: number;
    DAY_28?: number;
    DAY_29?: number;
    DAY_30?: number;
    DAY_31?: number;

    constructor() {
        this.DAY_1 = null;
        this.DAY_2 = null;
        this.DAY_3 = null;
        this.DAY_4 = null;
        this.DAY_5 = null;
        this.DAY_6 = null;
        this.DAY_7 = null;
        this.DAY_8 = null;
        this.DAY_9 = null;
        this.DAY_10 = null;
        this.DAY_11 = null;
        this.DAY_12 = null;
        this.DAY_13 = null;
        this.DAY_14 = null;
        this.DAY_15 = null;
        this.DAY_16 = null;
        this.DAY_17 = null;
        this.DAY_18 = null;
        this.DAY_19 = null;
        this.DAY_20 = null;
        this.DAY_21 = null;
        this.DAY_22 = null;
        this.DAY_23 = null;
        this.DAY_24 = null;
        this.DAY_25 = null;
        this.DAY_26 = null;
        this.DAY_27 = null;
        this.DAY_28 = null;
        this.DAY_29 = null;
        this.DAY_30 = null;
        this.DAY_31 = null;
    }
}
```